# How many VM's/ Machines can be configured as "SLAVE" Machines in Jmeter "MASTER"

Tags: performance, jmeter, query-optimization, performance-testing, master-slave

How many VM's/ Machines can be configured as "SLAVE" Machines in Jmeter "MASTER"

Is it limited to only 10 or can we configure upto 50 or limited to certain number?

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no strict limitation in [JMeter source code](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/JMeter.java#L1097), the list of slaves is basically an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) which size is an [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size--) so the maximum number of slaves is [2,147,483,647](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)

The actual limit depends on your hardware configuration, network throughput, memory, CPU, etc. so make sure to monitor these resources for master (as well as for the slaves and the application under test). If you don't have a better toolchain you can consider using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T, but I have another question now, can a Single Master be able to handle JTL files collection from all the slaves for suppose say 20 slaves connected to a Single Master?